# Problem displaying models built with migration in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, migrate

In Visual Studio, using migrations, when I run `update-database`, it says OK, the model is created in the database.

But when I open the database, there is no model, while when I run `update-database` in Visual Studio again, the error is that such an object already exists. Made but there is no model of this type in database where the problem can be? It is the same for all the models that I migrate

Comment: Pretty sure your object is there. Try refreshing the window in SSMS or just query sys.objects.

Comment: Are you querying the same database connected with VS Application?